# Shell Mysql Import Ignoring the Database name

Tags: mysql, import, ssh

For some odd reason my shell mysql import is ignoring the database name. Has anyone ever had that issue?

I am trying this.

```
mysql -u eds_myuser -p -h localhost eds_mydatabase < foo.sql
```

However this returns a different database connection error.

```
Access denied for user 'eds_myuser'@'localhost' to database 'differentdatabase'.
```

Any idea why that is? While it shows a different database name in the error than the one I typed out, it also doesn't show the `eds_` part either.

I can connect to mysql successfully, but when I run the above code I get that error.

Comment: Does `foo.sql` contain any statements like `USE differentdatabase`?  ie Does you script attempt to change db.

Comment: Yep, I just figured that out about 1 minute before you posted that. I can't believe that is what was causing it all along. See below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after an hour I finally found the issue. It is because of what the sql file contained!

```
--
-- Database: `differentdatabase`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `differentdatabase` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `differentdatabase`;
```

I know this will save someone a huge headache later on :)